# Retrieving xml from webservice - Android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am trying to get some data from a webservice, in my android app.

The code I am using is this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String highScore = null;
    int points = 0;

    try {
        URI uri = new URI("http://vestsoft.somee.com/api/scores");
        URL website = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());             

        InputStream inputStream = website.openStream();
        InputSource input = new InputSource(inputStream);

        SAXParserFactory saxp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = saxp.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlReader = sp.getXMLReader();

        HighScoreHandler handler = new HighScoreHandler();
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);

        xmlReader.parse(input); // Here is an exception thrown

        highScore = handler.highScore.getUserName();
        points = handler.highScore.getPoints();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return highScore + "  " + points;
}
```

I get an exception saying: 
"At line 1, column 0: syntax error"

I don't know what I am doing wrong. 
As you can see, the API I get my data from is: 
http://vestsoft.somee.com/api/scores

Comment: Can you paste the whole stack trace?  I am guessing the XML is not well formatted.

Comment: How do I get that?
In the "Java Stack Trace Console" there isn't anything.

Comment: I think you need to actually download/read the data first into a buffer before you can parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML lacks the correct header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Put that string at the top of your XML file and SAX Parser will stop bothering.

Answer (score 0):

There are some really nice open source XML parsing tools out there to make this a lot easier.  For example, to solve this with [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net), I would do it like this:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            URL website = new URL("http://vestsoft.somee.com/api/scores");

                            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                            HttpURLConnection conn = client.open(website);
                            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
                            InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                            Serializer serializer = new Persister();
                            ArrayOfScore scoreArray = serializer.read(ArrayOfScore.class, stream);

                            // do something with the ArrayScore object here

                        } catch (Exception err) {
                            Log.i(TAG, err.toString());
                        }
                    }
                };

                new Thread(r).start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This references two other classes, the XML annotated java classes.  They are:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
public class ArrayOfScore {

    @ElementList(inline=true,required=false)
    private List<Score> scores;

    public List<Score> getScores() {
        return scores;
    }

}
```

And:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="Score")
public class Score {

    @Element(name="Id",required=false)
    Integer Id;
    @Element(name="Name",required=false)
    String Name;
    @Element(name="Points",required=false)
    String Points;
    @Element(name="dateTime",required=false)
    String dateTime;
}
```

With this simple model you can parse nearly any XML you encounter and get the parsing into first class objects automatically.  There are similar classes for JSON such as [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)